# How do i sort a array of numbers having 10^6 digits using Java in an efficient way

Tags: java

How do i sort a array of numbers having 10^6 digits using Java in an efficient way

I am pretty sure we can do it with Strings

But Is there any other method without using Strings in Java.?

Comment: If they're numbers, you can't sort them as strings. Try `BigInteger`.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, you can sort them as strings, as long as they're all the same length (or you can make them the same length by left-padding with zeroes).  `BigInteger` is probably more efficient anyway, though.

Comment: @ajb I read it as *up to* 10^6 digits. Otherwise you're right of course.

Comment: Unless the numbers all share the same prefix comparisons will be pretty fast. What's your concern exactly? Memory usage?

Comment: @henry No its not about memory usage . I just wanted to know

Answer (score 5):

Use BigInteger and take advantage of Java's sort API

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new BigInteger("12"));
        list.add(new BigInteger("1223876987587658765876732097234987236497823649287346987324609234786923748601298763290444"));
        list.add(new BigInteger("126235812763548126375182763518236512983761927836012983719274629183746912874612948761298746912837342"));
        list.add(new BigInteger("32342"));

        Collections.sort(list);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
[12, 32342, 1223876987587658765876732097234987236497823649287346987324609234786923748601298763290444, 126235812763548126375182763518236512983761927836012983719274629183746912874612948761298746912837342]
```

Comment: @yshavit Gonna blame that stupidity on exhaustion. Thanks, updated :)